# Using Spotify webAPI to play random album of artist (ID)

Tags: html, node.js, asp.net-web-api, raspberry-pi, spotify

here is my "little" project, as I am not a developer myself please don't blame me for my stupid questions.

I want to create a "audio book machine".

I want to use a Website, that shows several Artists of audiobooks. If I click on one artist, a random audiobook of the clicked artist should be played.

I had a look at this code example: http://jsfiddle.net/qlmhuge/t7a1sh4u/

```
// find template and compile it
var templateSource = document.getElementById('results-template').innerHTML,
    template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource),
    resultsPlaceholder = document.getElementById('results'),
    playingCssClass = 'playing',
    audioObject = null;

var fetchTracks = function (albumId, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url:     'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/61qDotnjM0jnY5lkfOP7ve/albums/',
        success: function (response) {
            callback(response);
        }
    });
};

var searchAlbums = function (query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search',
        data: {
            q: 'artist:' + query,
            type: 'album',
            market: "DE"
        },
        success: function (response) {
            resultsPlaceholder.innerHTML = template(response);
        }
    });
};

results.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (target !== null && target.classList.contains('cover')) {
        if (target.classList.contains(playingCssClass)) {
            audioObject.pause();
        } else {
            if (audioObject) {
                audioObject.pause();
            }
            fetchTracks(target.getAttribute('data-album-id'), function(data)     {            
                audioObject = new Audio(data.tracks.items[0].preview_url);
                audioObject.play();
                target.classList.add(playingCssClass);
                audioObject.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                    target.classList.remove(playingCssClass);
                });
                audioObject.addEventListener('pause', function() {
                    target.classList.remove(playingCssClass);
               });
            });
        }
    }
});

searchAlbums('TKKG');
```

but I cannot figure out how to change it to play a random album by one artist.

The artist will be defindes by the spotify ID so that the artist ist the correct one.

Can someone help me out with my problem? What else info is needed to complete my goal?

I would be very thankful if one can give me a hint, or whatever, to get to the right direction.

Best regards,
goeste

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your `fetchTracks` function here:

```
var fetchTracks = function (albumId, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/' + albumId,
        success: function (response) {
            callback(response);
        }
    });
};
```

jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yheeo8vg/)

Comment: @goeste did you try attached jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi Oleg, yes i did but that was actually the example script from spotify. I wanted to get just an image (of my choice) an put a link behind it. the link should than start to play a random album of a certain musician/artist ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got a little closer to the finish line... well, I guess:

I found the following on [GitHub](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js):

```
var SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');

var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();

// credentials are optional
// var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
//   clientId : '',
//   clientSecret : '',
//   redirectUri : ''
// });

// Get albums by a certain artist
spotifyApi.getArtistAlbums('3meJIgRw7YleJrmbpbJK6S')
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('Artist albums', data.body);
  }, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

However, I only get 20 albums out of 35. I need to increase the limit. The max limit is 50, as I read on the developer site of Spotify. As I only need to get one out of the 35 albums (randomly), how can I implement the randomize function and also play function in order to work?

I am still figuring out how to create a link from the results to show on a website with node.js.

Best regards, and thank you in advance for any assistance/help!
-goeste

Comment: ok, got the limit figured out. I needed to change the request line: `spotifyApi.getArtistAlbums('3meJIgRw7YleJrmbpbJK6S', {limit: 50})`